# Seaborn Multiaxis Graph assigning different colors to the same/shared category Hue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

I'm making a combined bar and line graph, but the hue colors are different for each plot type even though their values are the same and everything is shared.

```
   report_date  shift  999  load_count
0   2019-03-31      1   42       227.0
1   2019-03-31      2   13       141.0
2   2019-03-31      3   79       267.0
3   2019-04-01      1  146       580.0
4   2019-04-01      2  177       627.0
5   2019-04-01      3  127       460.0
6   2019-04-02      1  192       583.0
7   2019-04-02      2  121       626.0
8   2019-04-02      3   98       291.0
9   2019-04-03      1  172       580.0
10  2019-04-03      2   83       372.0
11  2019-04-03      3   78       323.0
12  2019-04-04      1   83       403.0
13  2019-04-04      2   69       340.0
14  2019-04-04      3   86       268.0
15  2019-04-05      1  164       567.0
16  2019-04-05      2  169       593.0
17  2019-04-05      3   48       249.0
18  2019-04-06      1  102       304.0
19  2019-04-06      2   48       246.0
20  2019-04-06      3    4         0.0
```

```
dfg = df.set_index(['report_date', 'shift']).sort_index(level=[0,1])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))

ax2  = ax.twinx()

sns.barplot(x=dfg.index.get_level_values('report_date'),
            y=dfg.load_count,
           hue=dfg.index.get_level_values('shift'), ax=ax, alpha=0.7)

sns.lineplot(x=dfg.index.get_level_values('report_date'),
            y=dfg['999'],
           hue=dfg.index.get_level_values('shift'), ax=ax2, marker='o', legend=None)

ax.set_title('My Graph')
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph]

I even set the same Y category and even then the colors are different. If i change the color palette, the colors are still different, just different palette shades.

WHY is this happening? The categories are shared, so they should behave the same. Why is this happening?

Comment: While I do reproduce your current result with empty *palette* arg, I cannot reproduce: *If i change the color palette, the colors are still different, just different palette shades.* Please show this attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's because `sns` regards the line plots as different categories and render them as the same sequence with `barplots`. One way around is to specify the palette:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))

ax2  = ax.twinx()
palette = {1:'red', 2:'blue', 3:'green'}
sns.barplot(x=df['report_date'],
            y=df.load_count,
            hue=df['shift'], ax=ax, alpha=0.7,
            palette=palette)

sns.lineplot(x=df['report_date'],
             y=df['999'],
             hue=df['shift'], ax=ax2, marker='o', legend=None,
             palette=palette)

ax.set_title('My Graph')
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, hard coding the colors worked. I still don't understand why it's behaving so differently with this data versus the other graphs I have, especially when it comes to the date, but t least with this workaround i can make things happen!

Comment: And to get sns default colors: `palette=sns.color_palette()[0:3]`